# Elastic Beanstalk failing to answer requests even though it is not resource constrained

Tags: django-rest-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, locust

I have a Python 3.6 AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment with a DRF app with a single test endpoint that parses post data and forwards it to another service. I'm trying to figure out an appropriate trigger for the t2.micro autoscaling group with a minimum of 1 instance and a maximum of 4 instances.

For this purpose I'm using Locust (https://locust.io/) load testing framework for Python.

I tried an initial trigger based on CPUUtilization with upper threshold of 75% and lower threshold of 25% and a single initial instance. For incoming request rates above 50 requests/second the server failed to respond a significant number of requests yet CPUUtilization was never above 8%. Memory was never above 50% either.

In order to configure an appropriate trigger and ensure service continuity I need to know what is the binding resource that is failing above 50 requests/second rate. Any ideas?